# information about this type of selection in jquery $('.myclass',obj).length;

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

anyone know where can I get information about this Type of selection in jquery
I found it in a .js file and I want to know about it. 
I focus on Jquery api doc but in vain I dont find it.

```
var obj=$('#id1');
var t = $('.slidenews',obj).length;
```

exactly that what I want to know about.
var t = **$('.slidenews',obj)**.length;

Comment: `$('.slidenews',obj)` is an array of elements with the class `slidenews` inside an element with the `id1` and the `var t` is the amount of elements found

Comment: That would be the "context selector", and it's well documented in the documentation for selectors, -> [**Da DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$('...', element)` looks for `...` in `element` instead of the whole document. So in this case, it will look for all elements with class `slidenews` in the `#id1` element.
- `.length` returns the number of such elements found

Therefore, if `obj` contains the element with ID `id1`, then `$('.slidenews',obj).length` returns the number of elements with class `slidenews` that are contained inside the element with ID `id1`.

Relevant documentation:

- [`jQuery(selector, [context])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

  > **selector**
  >
  > Type: [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector)
  >
  > A string containing a selector expression
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **context**
  >
  > Type: [Element](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
  >
  > A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
- [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

  > **Description:** The number of elements in the jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

`$('.slidenews',obj)` is basically context selector. It will be converted into `obj.find('.slidenews')` and `.length` returns the no of such elements

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

> Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

Answer (score 0):

It same like:

```
obj.find('.slidenews')
```

In your case: `obj` - must be DOM object. if `obj` is falsy it will be replaced to `document`